# Add a keyboard shortcut to select the next question with favorite tag?

Tags: feature-request, keyboard-shortcuts

I didn't even know keyboard shortcuts existed until the new nav bar appears. I found these shortcuts really useful. I especially like the "select next/previous question" shortcut. However, there is one more shortcut that I would like to add.

What about adding a shortcut to select the next/previous question that's highlighted yellow (has my favorite tags)? I usually go to the "unanswered" section to look for questions to answer but using J and K to browse through the questions one by one is quite slow IMO. I don't look at the questions without my favorite tags anyways. Also, the page only scrolls when the selected question is at the bottom. My eyes need to keep looking up and down and up and down...